# how to call facebook javascript from a link?

Tags: javascript, facebook, hyperlink

i have this code:

```
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      // assume we are already logged in
      FB.init({appId: '123050457758183', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

      FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
          link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
          });
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

how do i call this function from this link: `<a href="#">test</a>`

any ideas?

thanks

edit: more about the facebook code [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use it this way:

```
<a href="#" id="go-to-fb"> click this </a>
```

in your jquery code:

```
$(function(){
   $("#go-to-fb").click(function(){
       FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
          link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
          });
})
})
```

Comment: There's no mention of jQuery here.

Comment: what does that mean? do i need to tell that jquery should be included?  <script type=text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>

Comment: It means that the OP never said they were using jQuery.  So, they might not know about it, or are using another framework.  Don't assume everyone uses jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the question. From the way I interpret it, it seems to me that all you need to do is have an onclick event for that hyperlink which runs the script you have provided.

Comment: I don't know javascript that well, but I can provide you the jQuery code.

Comment: @ruiyang: There is no mention of jQuery here.

Comment: i know how to use the `onclick` event, obviously I've tried it and it didn't work. that's why i asked if he can post some code i can relate to

Comment: @Patrioticcow: That's not obvious actually.  In you're code, you didn't have it, so how do we know you tried it?